# Getting data from arrays within array not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array which has some arrays but I cannot get the values from first array within the parent array only from the second one.

I don't know what is going on.

How can I get the values from first array within parent array in the first iteration and then the second one in the second iteration and so on. No matter the number of arrays within the parent?

my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>

<script>

var DetalleFactura=[[1, 2, 3],[6, 7, 8]];


DetalleFactura.forEach((subArr)=>{
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = subArr[0] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = subArr[1] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = subArr[2] + "<br>";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're reassigning the innerHtml every tteration, meaning you are clearing previous values. You can do  `.innerHTML += subArr[0] + "<br>";` rather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly getting the sub arrays, the problem is that you are overwriting the innerHtml with the last sub array. If you add one more sub array, the innerHtml will print the last item of `DetalleFactura`.

So, I think you may concat the innerHtml content like `.innerHtml += subArr[0] + "<br>";`

Answer (score 1):

Use += to append to the string rather than = which overwrites it.

```js
var DetalleFactura=[[1, 2, 3],[6, 7, 8]];

DetalleFactura.forEach((subArr)=>{
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += subArr[0] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += subArr[1] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML += subArr[2] + "<br>";
});
```

```html
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <style></style>
    <script>
        var arr = [ 0, [1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, [7, 8], 9], 10];

        // Remove nesting of multi-dimensional array and return vector of all
        // elements of a from top-to-bottom, left-to-right, etc. - also converts
        // scalar to singleton vector.
        function ravel(arg, flat) {var self = {name:'ravel'};
            // If flat - accumulator array - not yet defined, create it.
            if ('undefined' == typeof flat) flat = new Array();
            try { 
               // If arg is an array, iterate over the elements in index order.
               if (-1 != arg.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array')) {
                   // Call self recursively to get elements or process next, outermost
                   // level of nesting.
               for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {this.ravel(arg[i],flat);}
           }
           // Otherwise, just add simple element to accumulator.
           else flat.push( arg );
           // Return accumulated values.
           return flat;
           }
           catch (e) {console.log("ArraysException", e, self.name, null, arguments);}
        };

        function run () {
            var out = ravel( arr );
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="ravel and show array" onclick="run();"></input>
    </form>
    <p id="out">
        not clear how you intend to use the elements of the array - this just 
        strips all levels of nesting, leaving a flat, one-dimensional array 
        you can manipulate more easily
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```